# Mysql - Print all the values in between @loop_start_date to @loop_end_date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to: 
 
1. Print all the values in between @`loop_start_date` to `@loop_end_date`
2. `loop_start_date` should be increased by 1 here till `loop_start_date=loop_end_date`

I tried below but Mysql says

```
     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
        corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
 syntax to use near 'BEGIN   Declare @user_id int' at line 3
```

Here is the procedure code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE generatePayscale

BEGIN
    Declare @user_id int;
    Declare @office_id int;
    Declare @loop_start_date Date;
    Declare @loop_end_date Date;
    SET @user_id = 1287;
    SET @office_id = 8;
    SET @loop_start_date = '2018-06-02'; 
    SET @loop_end_date = '2018-06-06';


    WHILE(@loop_start_date < @loop_end_date) do 
        SELECT old_paysetupid 
        FROM   personneltransfer personnelid=@user_id 
        AND    pt.transferdate>@loop_start_date 
    END WHILE;
 END
```

Comment: In MySQL `WHILE` (and any procedural loop) can only be used in a *stored programm*. BTW: Your loop wouldn't even terminate.

Comment: The loop will run forever unless you change one of the variables during the loop. You need something like `SET @loop_start_date = DATE_ADD(@loop_start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)` to increment it.

Comment: You're missing the parameter list of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This may point you in the correct direction, a few things i would change.  Added `BEGIN`. Then added declare for each of the vars. Then you need a `where` after the from

```
SET @user_id = 1287;
SET @office_id = 8;
SET @loop_start_date = '2018-06-02'; 
SET @loop_end_date = '2018-06-06';

WHILE(@loop_start_date < @loop_end_date) do
BEGIN 
    SELECT old_paysetupid 
    FROM   personneltransfer where personnelid=@user_id 
    and pt.transferdate>@loop_start_date 
END WHILE;
```

Comment: I tried that MYsql says #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Declare @user_id int' at line 1

Comment: Hmm @user580950 try now without the declares, changed a thing about it too that I noticed

Comment: Now its throwing unrecognized statement type near while error

Comment: @user580950 Have you put the code in a stored procedure?

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question with the stored procedure but its throwing another error